# Testing string content on non-whitespace

Tags: python, whitespace

I want to test if a sentence contains anything else than white-space characters. This is what I use currently:

```
if len(teststring.split()) > 0:
    # contains something else than white space
else:
   # only white space
```

Is this good enough? Are there any better ways of doing it?

Comment: `' \t\n\v\f '.isspace()`. Done

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Strings have a method called [`str.isspace`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.isspace) which, according to the docs:

> Return[s] true if there are only whitespace characters in the string and there is at least one character, false otherwise.

So, that means:

```
if teststring.isspace():
    # contains only whitespace
```

Will do what you want.

Comment: `all(c.isspace() for c in teststring)` - little bit shorter :)

Comment: No comprehension needed: `' \t\n\v\f '.isspace()`

Comment: @JBernardo: Funny, the best answer from all of the answers listed here is your comment ;)

Answer (score 7):

I would use the [strip()](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=strip#str.strip) function for this purpose.

```
  if teststring.strip():
      # non blank line
  else:
      # blank line
```

Comment: @astynax Are you making a stylistic recommendation, or is there something wrong with my syntax/solution? Did I get a downvote for this? (Just asking .. since I can't tell)

Comment: @astynax Your suggested if-statement, if substituted into my code above gives the opposite (ie wrong) outcome. My solution is functional as far as I can tell.

Comment: Why the downvote? I am happy to correct any error or improve the answer, but that requires some constructive feedback. A downvote ***without*** explanation is not useful to OP, SO or me.

Comment: you are right of course: `if teststring.strip():`. -1: Checking the emptiness of string is cleaner, than the comparison with empty string (and slightly faster). Look [Truth Value Testing](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing)

Comment: @astynax Ok, thanks, I'll accept the functional/correct suggestion (and I agree it looks cleaner), though what I posted was correct from the start. I would never downvote a *functional* solution due to stylistic differences with someone else FWIW.

Comment: +1 for you. I apologize for the downvote. I just think that there is a lot of style guides for Python - enough to feel the "pythonic way".

Answer (score 2):

You can just use .strip().

Your resulting string will be empty if it is only whitespace.

```
if teststring.strip():
    # has something other than whitespace.
else:
    # only whitespace
```

Or perhaps more explicitly as JBernardo pointed out:

```
if not teststring.isspace():
    # has something other than whitespace

else:
    # only whitespace.
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 if teststring.split():
      print "not only whitespace!" 
 else:
     print ":("
```